# C - libcurl - How to get dltotal without using the CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION

Tags: c, libcurl

I am using the **libcurl** multi interface and I need to know how much data is being sent for each request. I would rather not use the `CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION` because it gets called a lot and I only need to know the dltotal while I am in the `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` callback. I want to clean up the existing easy handle and malloc'd data while I am still in the write callback once all the data has been received. Is there a function I can call that will return the total amount of data that is being sent for a particular easy handle?

I tried using `curl_easy_getinfo()` with `CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD` and it always returned **0**. I also tried `CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD` which also always returned **0**. I was calling this from within the  `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` callback.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get zeroes back from those calls is probably because the size simply isn't known before-hand.

But let me also alert you that *"I want to clean up the existing easy handle and malloc'd data while I am still in the write callback"* sounds like a disaster waiting to happen. You really should not cleanup the handle from within the callback.

Comment: Where do you recommend cleaning it up? In the code examples it shows using the event callback to clean up but that requires looping through all the current requests looking for requests that are done. That is a lot of looping for the number of requests I want to be doing. Plus the event callback fires far more often than I would need so that is even more looping than necessary.